# Add time to a date time using php

Tags: php, date, time

I have 3 fields in database startdate(datetime),global_time(time),enddate(datetime).Start date will be today datetime.

```
$start_date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s'); 
$global_time = '00:45:30'   // comes from database global_time
```

Now i want to sum $start_date and $global_time and store into database field enddate.Can anyone suggest me to how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$start_date  = new DateTime('2017-01-22 05:05:00');
$global_time = "00:45:30";
sscanf($global_time, "%d:%d:%d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
$time_seconds = isset($seconds) ? $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds : $hours * 60 + $minutes;//Converted in to seconds
$newtime="PT".$time_seconds."S";
$start_date->add(new DateInterval($newtime));
$enddate = $start_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $enddate;
```

---

```
PT0H45M30S for a interval of 0 hour, 45 minutes and 30 seconds.
```

Comment: @Devi.here $global_time is dynamically comes from database . so how can i dynamically set DateInterval value

Comment: Convert $global_time into seconds, then pass that value to DateInterval().